# weak_ptr - Dereferencing - Throw if expired

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, weak-ptr

Dereferencing a `weak_ptr` does not automatically check whether the pointer has expired. Why is it designed this way ?

I would like to safely dereference weak pointers without first having to check them using `expired()` and throw an exception if they are null.

Would this be a good practice and what would be a right way to do that ? Should I overload `*` and `->` operators so that they perform this check first ? Should I write a free function ?

Something like :

```
template< typename T >
weak_ptr< T > & check( weak_ptr< T > & p )
{
    if( p.expired() )
        throw logic_error( "Trying to dereference a null pointer." );
    return p;
}
```

And then :

```
weak_ptr< int > pi;
int i = *check( pi );
```

Thank you.

Comment: but... you cannot dereference a weak pointer. you have to lock it, get a shared one from it and use that one.

Comment: You are supposed to convert/create a shared_ptr from them before accessing the raw pointer to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `expired()` is not useful because it will introduce races in multi-threaded programs. Also an exception is not nice, because having a `weak_ptr` expired is not so exceptional: they are designed precisely for that.

The nice trick around `weak_ptr` is that they are not dereferenceable. Instead, to access the object you call `lock()` that atomically returns a `shared_ptr` that points to the object, or to `null` if not available.

The normal way to access a weak pointer is:

```
void safe_do(weak_ptr<T> &w)
{
    shared_ptr<T> p = w.lock();
    if (p)
        p->do();
}
```

If you really want the exception, you can use this variant:

```
void safe_do2(weak_ptr<T> &w)
{
    shared_ptr<T>(w)->do(); //throws a bad_weak_ptr if w expired
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understand what you wrote correctly, the simple fact of trying to convert the weak_ptr into a shared_ptr that can be dereferenced will throw if the weak_ptr expired ? In that case I don't need to add any extra checking, do I ?

Comment: @Virus721  No it will create a NULL shared_ptr which you can then test for.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you. So what I have to do is write a function that takes a shared_ptr which is given by lock(), throw an exception if it is null, and then return this same shared_ptr which can then be safely dereferenced, right ? EDIT Yeah that's basically what the answer says except that the safe_do method performs the call instead of returning the checked shared_ptr. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, the `shared_ptr(weak_ptr &)` constructor will throw if expired. The `weak_ptr::lock()` function will return null.